# GNU Screen does not work when su'ing from root to a normal user

Tags: terminal, permissions, gnu-screen, root

Is it normal, that when I am logged in as root, and the used `su user`, I can't access that users screen sessions?

In this case, screen complains about it not having permissions on `/dev/pts/x`.

I assume that it can't control the terminal which was opened as root in the way it needs: am I right?

Comment: Have you tried using 'su - user' ?

Comment: @tripledes Tried it just now, did not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you can change the ownership of /dev/pts/x to the user that you su to, as root, before you actually su. That way, the user that you su to will have access to attach the screen to your origin terminal.

```
# chown someuser /dev/pts/x
# su - someuser
$ screen -dr somescreen
```

If this is something you want to make more smooth, you could look into how ownership is set on terminal devices, so that you could, say, make them group read/writable, and have a small group where users have access. This can have severe security implications, so do take care if you're exploring that path!

Comment: Ok. That's what I did. I created an "alternative su", which executes `chown :mygroup $(tty)`and the `su $1` I added the users to the group

Comment: I worry about the security implications of changing the ownership of the device file, so my workaround is to simply run `script /dev/null` right before I run screen.